# How can the width of a chart in wpf be adjusted?

Tags: wpf, charts, wpftoolkit

I am using the chart control from the WPF Toolkit. My question is simple, when my chart is displayed, the column is expanded to the width of the screen.

Is there a way to specify a maximum width? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a width explicitly via the `Width` property, or allow an element to expand up to a certain size via the `MaxWidth` property. These properties are common to all UI elements, not just charts.

See the [FrameworkElement documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)